# readout a big txt file

Tags: c++

i want to know, if there is another way to readout a big file

```
Hans //name

Bachelor // study_path

WS10_11 //semester

22 // age
```

and not like this:

```
fout >> name; //string

fout >> study_path; //string

fout >> Semester ; //string

fout >> age; //int
```

when my file turns to more than 20 line's i should make 20+ fouts?

Is there another way?

Comment: You might want to learn about loops.

Comment: And another hint (SCNR): Use international identifiers and comments. Hier können nur wenige deutsch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could define a class to hold the data for each person:

```
class Person {
public:
    std::string name;
    std::string study_path;
    std::string semester;
    unsigned int age;
};
```

Then you can define a stream extraction operator for that class:

```
std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & stream, Person & person) {
    stream >> person.name >> person.study_path >> person.semester >> person.age;
    return stream;
}
```

And then you can just read the entire file like that:

```
std::ifstream file("datafile.txt");
std::vector<Person> data;
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<Person>(file), std::istream_iterator<Person>(),
          std::back_inserter(data));
```

This will read the entire file and store all the extracted records in a `vector`. If you know the number of records you will read in advance, you can call `data.reserve(number_of_records)` before reading the file. Thus, the vector will have enough memory to store all records without reallocation, which might potentially speed up the loading if the file is large.

Comment: I'd make age `unsigned` unless you need to process unborn students.

Comment: @demonking: If an answer solves your problem, you can accept it as correct using the tick to the left of the answer. This makes it easier to find for others with the same problem, and it rewards thoe that take the time to answer (consider this also for your other two questions).

Comment: It is [adviced](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Operators/Operator_Overloading#Bitwise_operators) to overload `>>` as `friend`. MVC at least will not even accept it, if it is not declared as such.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on linux, you can [mmap()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) the big file, and use data as it is in memory.